# Exception in java : declared variable but the compiler can not read it

Tags: java

I have a java program which has compilation errors. I created 2 classes "magasin" and "produit", the class "magasin" contains a list of "produit"

- when we create a "produit"an exception"ProdException" can be thrown.
- when we add a "produit" in the list in "magasin"class: an exception "prixException"can be thrown.

here is 'magasin'class:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package GestionMag;
import GestionMag.Produit;

import static java.lang.System.in;
import java.util.Vector;

/**
 *
 * @author USER
 */
public class Magasin {
    private int id;
    private String adresse;
    private final int capProd=2;
    private Vector<Produit> prod = new Vector<Produit>();
    private int nbProd;
    private final int capEmp=20;
    private Vector<Employe> emp = new Vector<Employe>();

    public Magasin(){}
    public Magasin(int a,String b)
    {
     id=a;
     adresse=b;
     nbProd=0;
    }
    public int getId(){return id;}
    public String getAdresse(){return adresse;}
    public int getCapProd(){return capProd;}

    public void setId(int a){id=a;}
    public void setAdresse(String a){adresse=a;}
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "\n id"+id+" adresse:"+adresse+" capProd"+capProd+"nbPrd="+nbProd;
    }
    public void afficher()
    {
        System.out.println(this.toString());
        System.out.println("----------Produits");
        for(Produit p : prod)
        {
            System.out.println(p.toString());
        }
         System.out.println("----------Employes");
        for(Employe p : emp)
        {
            System.out.println(p.toString());
        }
    }
    public boolean rechercher(Produit p)
    {
        return prod.contains(p);
    }
    public boolean chercherEmp(Employe e)
    {
         return emp.contains(e);
    }
    public boolean ajouterEmp(Employe e)
    {
        if(!chercherEmp(e))
        {emp.add(e);
         return true;}
        return false;    }
    public boolean ajouterProd(Produit p) throws ExceptionProd
    { if (nbProd>=capProd)
        throw new ExceptionProd();
        if(!this.rechercher(p))
        {
            prod.add(p);
            nbProd++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public void supprimerProd(Produit p)
    {
        prod.remove(p);
    }
     public void supprimerEmp(Employe p)
    {
        emp.remove(p);
    }

}
```

here is 'produit' class:

```
package GestionMag;

import java.util.Date;
import GestionMag.PrixException;

/**
 *
 * @author USER
 */
public class Produit {
    private int id;
    private String libelle;
    private String marque;
    private double prix;
    private Date dateExp;

    public Produit(){};
    public Produit(int a,String b,String c,Date d) 
    {   
        id=a;
        libelle=b;
        marque=c;
        dateExp=d;
    }
    public Produit(int a,String b,String c,double  e,Date d) throws PrixException
    {
        if(prix<0)
            throw new PrixException();
        else{
        id=a;
        libelle=b;
        marque=c;
        prix=e;
        dateExp=d;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "id="+id+"  libelle:"+libelle+"  marque:"+marque+"  prix"+prix+"  DateExpiration"+dateExp;
    }
    public int getId(){return id;}
    public String getLibelle(){return libelle;}
    public String getMarquue(){return marque;}
    public double getPrix(){return prix;}
    public Date getDateExp(){return dateExp;}

    public void setId(int a){id=a;}
    public void setLibelle(String a){libelle=a;}
    public void setMarque(String a){marque=a;}
    public void setPrix(double a)throws PrixException
    {  if(prix<0)
        throw new PrixException();
       else
        prix=a;
    }
    public void setDateExp(Date d){dateExp=d;}

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if(o==null)
        {return false;}
        if(o.getClass()!=this.getClass())
            return false;
        if(o.getClass()==this.getClass())
        {
            Produit p=(Produit)o;
            if(p.getId()==this.getId())
                return true;
            else
                return false;

        }
    return false;
    }  
}
```

here is the main:

```
public class Prosit1 {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
     Date d=new Date(22-22-1010);


        Produit p=new Produit(1021,"lait","delice",d);
        Produit p1=new Produit(3333,"yaourt","delice",d);
        try
        {
            Produit p2=new Produit(2222,"lait","delice",-22,d);
        }
        catch(PrixException e)
        {
            System.out.println("erreur prix < 0");
        }
        Magasin m=new Magasin(12,"Aziza al ghazella");

        try
        { m.ajouterProd(p2);
        }
        catch(ExceptionProd e)
        {
            System.out.println("erreuuur");
        }
```

when compiling an error is produced: can not find symbol p2.
when executing an exception is displayed:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - exception GestionMag.ExceptionProd is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
>           at prosit1.Prosit1.main(Prosit1.java:71)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to reduce the source code to the minimum that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Hint: when the compiler refuses to compile your classes, there is **zero** point in trying to run that.

Answer (score 5):

In short you're trying to do this:

```
try {
    Produit p2 = new Produit(2222, "lait", "delice", -22, d);
} catch (PrixException e) {
    System.out.println("erreur prix < 0");
}

try {
    m.ajouterProd(p2);
} catch (ExceptionProd e) {
    System.out.println("erreuuur");
}
```

---

The 2nd `try` block does not know the definition of `p2` since it's defined in another `try` block. Here are some ways you can solve it:

NOTE: This is only addressing your issue and not a copy and paste solution.

### Possible solution 1:

Defining `p2` outside either `try` block.

```
Produit p2 = null;
try {
    p2 = new Produit(2222, "lait", "delice", -22, d);
} catch (PrixException e) {
    System.out.println("erreur prix < 0");
}

try {
    m.ajouterProd(p2);
} catch (ExceptionProd e) {
    System.out.println("erreuuur");
}
```

### Possible solution 2:

Executing the code in a single `try` block and catch multiple exceptions at once.

```
try {
    Produit p2 = new Produit(2222, "lait", "delice", -22, d);
    m.ajouterProd(p2);
} catch (PrixException e) {
    System.out.println("erreur prix < 0");
} catch (ExceptionProd e) {
    System.out.println("erreuuur");
}
```

Comment: thank you Mark , i understand the problem ,it works now.